# How to set up a systemd service to retry 5 times on a cycle of 30 seconds

Tags: service, systemd

I want systemd to start a script and retry a maximum of 5 times, 30s apart.
Reading the systemd.service manual and searching the Internet didn't produce any obvious answers.

Comment: Just in case this is how you could do it with [immortal](https://immortal.run/post/retries/) `immortal -w 30 -r 5 <your command>`

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/736624/systemd-service-automatic-restart-after-startlimitinterval/962338

Answer (score 108):

To allow a maximum of 5 retries separated by 30 seconds use the following options in the relevant systemd service file.

```
[Unit]
StartLimitInterval=200
StartLimitBurst=5

[Service]
Restart=always
RestartSec=30
```

This worked for a service that runs a script using `Type=idle`. Note that `StartLimitInterval` must be greater than `RestartSec * StartLimitBurst` otherwise the service will be restarted indefinitely. The service is considered `failed` when restarted `StartLimitBurst` times within `StartLimitInterval`.

See https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#StartLimitIntervalSec=interval and https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#RestartSec=

Comment: It's maybe worth noting that -- according to the official systemd manpages -- RestartSec and Restart are part of [System], whereas StartLimitInterval and StartLimitBurst are part of [Unit].

Comment: What does StartLimitInterval do?

Comment: @GerhardHagerer When you say [System], I think you mean [Service]. This worked for me.

Comment: also worked for 'Type= forking' for me, if that means anything.

Comment: also, more details 
here: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#
and here: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Examples

Comment: Note this is only true for systemd < 230. See this answer for newer versions of systemd https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/463917/systemds-startlimitintervalsec-and-startlimitburst-never-work/464098#464098