# Systemd's StartLimitIntervalSec and StartLimitBurst never work

Tags: linux, systemd

I tried to restrict the number of a service (in a container) restart. The OS version is centos-release-7-5, the service file is pretty much as below (removed some parameters for reading convenience). It should be pretty straight forward as some other posts pointed out ([Post of Server Fault restart limit 1](https://serverfault.com/questions/736624/systemd-service-automatic-restart-after-startlimitinterval) , [Post of Stack Overflow restart limit 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39284563/how-to-set-up-a-systemd-service-to-retry-5-times-on-a-cycle-of-30-seconds) ). Yet StartLimitBurst and StartLimitIntervalSec never works for me.

I tested with several ways: (1) I check the service PID, kill the service with "kill -9 ****" several times. The service always gets restarted after 20s! (2) I also tried to mess up the service file, make the container never runs. Still, it doesn't work, the service file just keep restarting.

Any idea?

```
[Unit]
Description=Hello Fluentd
After=docker.service
Requires=docker.service
StartLimitBurst=2
StartLimitIntervalSec=150s

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/environment
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker stop "fluentd"
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker rm -f "fluentd"
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run fluentd
ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker stop "fluentd"
Restart=always
RestartSec=20s
SuccessExitStatus=143

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it has been asked by the OP and answered successfully at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/463917/systemds-startlimitintervalsec-and-startlimitburst-never-work

Answer (score -1):

I posted the problem in UNIT stack exchange. Anyway in case somebody search it here, I also posted my answer here since I found the issue. All the doc online suggests those all parameters are in UNIT file ([systemd unit file](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#)), but still in my system (centos 7.5), they are in service file. Besides the name is "StartLimitInterval", not "StartLimitIntervalSec".

Comment: There is actually a `StartLimitIntervalSec` but that only exists in sytemd version >= 230 https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2017-July/039255.html