# How to restart Systemd service only once on-failure?

Tags: linux, systemd

I have a service that should restart only once when something go wrong.
Here is my service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Do job on boot
AllowIsolate=yes
StartLimitBurst=1    # or 2
StartLimitIntervalSec=3

[Service]
User=root
Type=idle

ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /var/www/flask/initJobs.py
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=3

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But this on failure keep restarting.

systemd version 241.

Tried to add `StartLimitAction=none` but did not change nothing.

Comment: Hi @Zorro, based on what I know it is not possible. The interval has to be limited in time.... But I could be as long as 100years ...which is close to unlimited right ? Would that work for you to only allow one retry every 100 year ?
if so : https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#StartLimitIntervalSec=interval and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39284563/how-to-set-up-a-systemd-service-to-retry-5-times-on-a-cycle-of-30-seconds could help.

Comment: Good trick! Can works if `RestartSec` is counted after the first restart. And won't work if i need 2 restarts. I think it could be possible to abord after n restart.

Comment: I think you can make it work for any number of retries.

Comment: `StartLimitIntervalSec=100y, StartLimitBurst=1` would only trigger one restart `StartLimitIntervalSec=100y, StartLimitBurst=10` would tigger 10

Comment: using StartLimitIntervalSec=100y and StartLimitBurst=1 on first restart i got: `Failed to start Job Service`  `myJob.service: Start request repeated too quickly`

Comment: Try to increase the StartLimitBurst .... The first start must count has one burst.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok i found, so to restart service only once on failure after 3 second.

```
[Unit]
Description=Do job on boot
StartLimitBurst=2
StartLimitInterval=11          # StartLimitInterval >  RestartSec * StartLimitBurst
#OR
#StartLimitIntervalSec=11  

[Service]
User=root
Type=idle

ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /var/www/flask/initJobs.py
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=3

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

the key here is `StartLimitIntervalSec` have to be > to `RestartSec * StartLimitBurst` and `StartLimitBurst` count the first start.